# Linux Kernel Module unix domain sockets

Tags: android, linux, sockets, unix-socket

I'm trying to share data between kernel and user space. The ultimate goal is to port it to Android, so I'm using unix domain sockets. (I don't know if this is the best option).

I have a kernel module acting as socket client and a c program acting as socket server. And vice-versa, a kernel module acting as socket server and a c program acting as socket client.

Programs are very simple. Servers just send a string to clients and they print it.

I run **server_user.c** and then I try to insert **client_module.ko** using insmod. I get the following error:

```
Kernel panic - not syncing: stack - protector: Kernel stack is corrupted in: ffffffffa0005157

drm-kms-helper: panic occurred, switching back to text console
```

What's wrong?

Module Server

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/socket.h>
#include <linux/net.h>
#include <linux/un.h>
#include <net/sock.h>

#define SOCK_PATH   "/tmp/usocket"
#define LISTEN      10

struct socket *sock = NULL;
struct socket *newsock = NULL;

static int __init server_module_init( void ) {

  int retval;
  char* string = "hello_world";

  struct sockaddr_un addr;
  struct msghdr msg;
  struct iovec iov;
  mm_segment_t oldfs;

  // create
  retval = sock_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, &sock);

  memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
  addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
  strcpy(addr.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);

  // bind
  retval = sock->ops->bind(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));

  // listen
  retval = sock->ops->listen(sock, LISTEN);

  //accept
  retval = sock->ops->accept(sock, newsock, 0);

  //sendmsg
  memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
  memset(&iov, 0, sizeof(iov));

  msg.msg_name = 0;
  msg.msg_namelen = 0;
  msg.msg_iov = &iov;
  msg.msg_iov->iov_base = string;
  msg.msg_iov->iov_len = strlen(string)+1;
  msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
  msg.msg_control = NULL;
  msg.msg_controllen = 0;
  msg.msg_flags = 0;

  oldfs = get_fs();
  set_fs(KERNEL_DS);

  retval = sock_sendmsg(newsock, &msg, strlen(string)+1);

  set_fs(oldfs);

  return 0;
}

static void __exit server_module_exit( void ) {
  printk(KERN_INFO "Exit usocket.");
}

module_init( server_module_init );
module_exit( server_module_exit );
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Module Client

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/un.h>
#include <linux/net.h>
#include <net/sock.h>
#include <linux/socket.h>

#define SOCK_PATH   "/tmp/usocket"
#define MAX     100

struct socket *sock = NULL;


static int __init client_module_init( void ) {

  int retval;
  char str[MAX];

  struct sockaddr_un addr;
  struct msghdr msg;
  struct iovec iov;
  mm_segment_t oldfs;

  printk(KERN_INFO "Start client module.\n");

  // create
  retval = sock_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, &sock); 

  // connect
  memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));  
  addr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
  strcpy(addr.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);

  retval = sock->ops->connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr), 0);

  // recvmsg

  memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
  memset(&iov, 0, sizeof(iov));

  msg.msg_name = 0;
  msg.msg_namelen = 0;
  msg.msg_iov = &iov;
  msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
  msg.msg_iov->iov_base= str;
  msg.msg_iov->iov_len= strlen(str)+1;
  msg.msg_control = NULL;
  msg.msg_controllen = 0;
  msg.msg_flags = 0;

  oldfs = get_fs();
  set_fs(KERNEL_DS);

  retval = sock_recvmsg(sock, &msg, strlen(str)+1, 0);

  set_fs(oldfs);

  // print str
  printk(KERN_INFO "client module: %s.\n",str);

  // release socket
  sock_release(sock);

  return 0;
}

static void __exit client_module_exit( void )
{
  printk(KERN_INFO "Exit client module.\n");
}

 module_init( client_module_init );
 module_exit( client_module_exit );
 MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

User Server

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>

#define SOCK_PATH "/tmp/usocket"

int send_msg_to_client(int socketfd, char* data) {

  struct msghdr msg;
  struct iovec iov;
  int s;

  memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
  memset(&iov, 0, sizeof(iov));

  msg.msg_name = NULL;
  msg.msg_namelen = 0;
  iov.iov_base = data;
  iov.iov_len = strlen(data)+1;
  msg.msg_iov = &iov;
  msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
  msg.msg_control = NULL;
  msg.msg_controllen = 0;
  msg.msg_flags = 0;

  s = sendmsg(socketfd, &msg, 0);

  printf("after send - iov_base: %s, length: %d\n", (char *) msg.msg_iov->iov_base, (int) strlen(msg.msg_iov->iov_base));

  if(s < 0){
    perror("sendmsg");
    return 0;
  }

  return s;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

        if (argc != 2) {
          printf("Usage: $ %s <string>\n",argv[0]);
          return 0;
        }

    int s, s2, len, slen;
    socklen_t t;
    struct sockaddr_un local, remote;
    char* data = argv[1];

    printf("print data: %s\n",data);

    if ((s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&local, 0, sizeof(local));
    local.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(local.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);

    unlink(local.sun_path);

    len = strlen(local.sun_path) + sizeof(local.sun_family);
    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr *)&local, len) == -1) {
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (listen(s, 5) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Waiting for a connection...\n");

    t = sizeof(remote);
    if ((s2 = accept(s, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, &t)) == -1) {
        perror("accept");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Connected.\n");

    slen = send_msg_to_client(s2, data);

    if(slen < 0)
        perror("send");

    close(s2);

    return 0;
}
```

User Client

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>

#define SOCK_PATH "/tmp/usocket"
#define MAX 100

int recv_msg_from_server(int socketfd, char data[MAX]) {

  struct msghdr msg;
  struct iovec iov;
  int s;

  memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
  memset(&iov, 0, sizeof(iov));

  msg.msg_name = NULL;
  msg.msg_namelen = 0;
  iov.iov_base = data;
  iov.iov_len = MAX;
  msg.msg_iov = &iov;
  msg.msg_iovlen = 1;
  msg.msg_control = NULL;
  msg.msg_controllen = 0;
  msg.msg_flags = 0;


  s = recvmsg(socketfd, &msg, 0);

  printf("after recv - iov_base: %s, length: %d\n", (char *) msg.msg_iov->iov_base, (int) strlen(msg.msg_iov->iov_base));

  if(s < 0){
    perror("recvmsg");
  }

  return s;
}


int main(void)
{
    int s, len, slen;
    struct sockaddr_un remote;
    char data[MAX];

    if ((s = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
            perror("socket");
            exit(1);
        }

    printf("Trying to connect...\n");

    memset(&remote, 0, sizeof(remote));

    remote.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strcpy(remote.sun_path, SOCK_PATH);
    len = strlen(remote.sun_path) + sizeof(remote.sun_family);

    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&remote, len) == -1) {
            perror("connect");
            exit(1);
        }

    printf("Connected.\n");

    slen = recv_msg_from_server(s, data);

    if (slen < 0) {
        perror("recvmsg");
    }

    //printf("print data received > %s\n", data);

    close(s);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps including the output of your kernel log at the time of the panic would help. Without it, you're asking people to speculate or attempt to build your module and replicate your results.

Comment: I have tried the same thing and got the same error (when calling connect on a created socket). After several trial, I found that if I allocate sockaddr_un structure in kernel heap by kmalloc it looks working, though I don't know why. Anyone know why it works? (Could be like my heap is also corrupted but working by lack...)

Comment: I also tried to add -fno-stack-protector compiler flag to avoid stack check. This also avoids the error (obviously since the error occurs in the check.) . I still don't have enough confident that if the stack checker is correct or not...

Answer (score 3):

I have just faced a similar issue (with UNIX datagrams though), and I believe there is a bug in the [unix_mkname()](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/unix/af_unix.c?v=4.1#L215) function which is part of the kernel: this function makes sure the `sun_path` field of the given `sockaddr_un` structure is always null terminated by adding a NUL character **after** the end of that field. Since this is the last field, it will corrupt the area (stack or heap) where that structure has been allocated.

The best solution is to patch that function in the kernel source code, so that it only sets to NUL the last character of the `sun_path` field. Meanwhile, you can make your code work by decreasing by 1 byte the size you give for the `sockaddr_un` structure:

Module Server

```c
  // bind
  retval = sock->ops->bind(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr) - 1);
```

Module Client

```c
 retval = sock->ops->connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr) - 1, 0);
```

As I am using UNIX datagrams, I cannot really tell if it fixes the issue for `bind()` and `connect()`, but a least, it fixes it for `sock_sendmsg()`.

@shu-suzuki: thanks for the leads.

Answer (score 1):

After 5 years I came back here...
I again stucked with this problem and found that I did the same thing 5 years ago.

The cause is as in Tey's answer and the solution is OK (sutbract 1 from the length) but here's another solution.

What you can do is to use `struct sockaddr_storage` as `struct sockaddr_un`. As far as I read the kernel code this is what they use to handle bind system call from user space.
`sockeaddr_storage` is larger than `sockaddr_un` so kernel code can write beyond the sizeof(sockaddr_un).

The code should be like

```
struct sockaddr_storage addrStorage;
struct sockaddr_un* addr;
memset(&addrStorage, 0, sizeof(addrStorage));
addr = (struct sockaddr_un*)&addrStorage;
addr->sun_family = AF_UNIX;
strcpy(addr->sun_path, "/my/sock/name");
kernel_bind(listenSock, (struct sockaddr*)addr, sizeof(*addr));
```

This looks working for me.